# For loop generating multiple XML requests in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, for-loop, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I need to access a series of XML documents and am trying to do so with a for loop that generates each request dynamically:

```
for (i=0;i<routes.length;i++) {
routeRequestURL = "http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeConfig&a=sf-muni&r=" + routes[i].name + "&terse";
routeRequest.open("GET", routeRequestURL);
routeRequest.send();
routeResponse = routeRequest.responseXML;
route = routeResponse.getElementsByTagName("route")[0];
for (var j = 0; j < route.childNodes.length; j++) {
    if (route.childNodes[j].tagName == "stop") {
        routes[i].stops.push(new Stop(route.childNodes[j].getAttribute("tag"), route.childNodes[j].getAttribute("lat"), route.childNodes[j].getAttribute("lon")));
    }
  }
}
```

`routes` is an array of `route` objects, which have three variables: `name`, `label`, and `stops`, which is itself an array of `stop` objects.

I tried out the code in Chrome's javascript console, and it worked when I ran each line within the outer loop with `routes[0]`. When I tried to run the loop in the console, I got the following error message: `TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null`.

If running each line of code with `routes[0]` generates no errors, then why is `routeResponse` null during the first iteration of the for loop? Am I missing a closure error somewhere?

**EDIT:** I tried to include a `readystatechange` callback, but, being new to javascript, couldn't quite figure out how to do it. I tried:

```
for (i=0;i<routes.length;i++) {
routeRequestURL = "http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeConfig&a=sf-muni&r=" + routes[i].name + "&terse";
routeRequest.open("GET", routeRequestURL);
routeRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    routeResponse = routeRequest.responseXML;
    route = routeResponse.getElementsByTagName("route")[0];
    for (var j = 0; j < route.childNodes.length; j++) {
        if (route.childNodes[j].tagName == "stop") {
            routes[i].stops.push(new Stop(route.childNodes[j].getAttribute("tag"), route.childNodes[j].getAttribute("lat"), route.childNodes[j].getAttribute("lon")));
        }
      }
    }
routeRequest.send();
}
```

It didn't work.

Comment: You're missing a `readystatechange` callback, since the request is asynchronous.

Comment: I'm pretty new to javascript... how would I include that callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Inside the `readystatechange` callback you added, you have to check if the response has finished loading
2. The callback introduces a closure, which will cause you problems with your reference to `i`.

The following code should address both issues:

```
routeRequest.onreadystatechange = (function(i) { return function() {
    if(routeRequest.readyState == 4 && routeRequest.status == 200) {
        routeResponse = routeRequest.responseXML;
        route = routeResponse.getElementsByTagName("route")[0];
        for (var j = 0; j < route.childNodes.length; j++) {
            if (route.childNodes[j].tagName == "stop") {
                routes[i].stops.push(new Stop(route.childNodes[j].getAttribute("tag"), route.childNodes[j].getAttribute("lat"), route.childNodes[j].getAttribute("lon")));
            }
        }
     }
}})(i);
```